# Do i also need to return string outside if-else condition ,when the return type is String

Tags: java, return

[image]The compiler keeps telling to return string.I used if-else condition and from within if-else i have returned string.The compiler problem will be solved if i put return statement at the end of the code but my problem will start .I dont understand how to solve this problem.I want to return right when its right.

Code:

```
public String isValidID(String id) {
     if(getId().length()!=6) {//checks for 6 digit id
         return "wrong";
     }
     else{//checks if digit contains invalid entry
        for(int i=0;i<getId().length();i++){
            if(Id.charAt(i)>'9'||Id.charAt(i)<'0')
                return "wrong";
            }
     }


}
```

Comment: Just add `return "right";` (or whatever it is you should return when the ID is valid) at the end, after the closing `}` on the `else`. Your code returns `"wrong"` when it finds a problem with the ID, but if the ID doesn't have any problems, you need to return *something* since a non-`void` method always returns something.

Comment: What does this function return if the input is `"111111"`?  The function must return a string in *every* case, but this case seems not to be covered.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder but that will make the program return "right " always.Becoz after if-else condition check ,the compiler will execute rest statement and will return "right" always ...

Comment: Why do you pass `id` but then check the length of `getId()`?

Comment: return statements stop the execution of a function and return the specified result to the function that called them. If it hits one of the other return "wrong" statements, it will not continue to any subsequent code.

Comment: @MaizerePathak.Nepal - No, it won't. `return` immediately exits the function. So for instance, `return "wrong"` stops your loop immediately and exits the function with the return value `"wrong"`. I've [posted an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50542784/157247) to explain more thoroughly, now that I understand what you don't understand. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder why do i need to add return statement at the end than ??becoz its coverd in if-else condition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In reply to my comment to add `return "right"` at the end, you said:

> but that will make the program return "right " always.Becoz after if-else condition check ,the compiler will execute rest statement and will return "right" always

Now the source of your confusion is clear: `return` doesn't just set the value the method will return, it **also** exits the method, immediately. So for instance, the `return "wrong";` inside your loop will exit from the loop, and the method, immediately. This is true of all the languages I've seen that use the `return` keyword (whereas there are some languages, like VB/VB.Net, where you assign a value to the function's name to set the return value, but execution continues normally until you use "exit").

That's why adding `return "right";` at the end is how you resolve this, because the code won't reach that point if it ever reached `return "wrong";` during the program flow above it:

```
public String isValidID(String id) {
     if(getId().length()!=6) {//checks for 6 digit id
         return "wrong";                        // <== Exits immediately if reached
     }
     else{//checks if digit contains invalid entry
        for(int i=0;i<getId().length();i++){
            if(Id.charAt(i)>'9'||Id.charAt(i)<'0')
                return "wrong";                 // <== Exits immediately if reached
            }
     }
     return "right";                            // <== Exits immediately if reached
                                                // (granted, we would have exited
                                                // below anyway :-) )
}
```

Comment: yes i understand but why do i need to add return statement at the end ??

Comment: @MaizerePathak.Nepal what would it do if the string were `000000`?

Comment: @MaizerePathak.Nepal - Because the function has to return a string (or `null`, but that's a detail); you've said it will, and so all paths out of the function have to do that. Think of it from the point of view of calling your function `String result = obj.isValidId("123456");` There has to be something to assign to `result`.

Answer (score 1):

In any condition, you need to return "something". In your code it possible that `return` never executed in a certain condition. Suppose your program execution comes to `if(Id.charAt(i)>'9'||Id.charAt(i)<'0')` and it never gets `true` then what the method will return? So, You need to write the code in a manner that in condition method execution will execute a return statement which returns a String object.

Just imagine a conditon Suppose

```
1. getId().length()!=6 -> false
2. getId().length() is 0 
3. for(int i=0;i<getId().length();i++) will never enter the loop.
```

Then what should the method returns when you call it.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your else you have another if statement, so your return its not always reached. You need another return after the for cycle.
And you are checking if something is wright or wrong you should return Boolean true or false.

public boolean isValidID(String id) { if(getId().length()!=6) {//checks for 6 digit id return false; } 
else{//checks if digit contains invalid entry for(int i=0;i'9'||Id.charAt(i)<'0') return false; } 
return true;// when nothing false was found.
}
 }

Answer (score 0):

If I can understand your logic you can just use :

```
public String isValidID(String id) {
   return id.matches("\\d{6}") ? "correct" : "wrong";
}
```

You check the length if it is 6 or not then you check if all characters are digits, you can combine both of them in one instruction, just check if the input is a number with length 6 with regex.

If you want a clean solution use `boolean` instead of a String in this case you can use :

```
public boolean isValidID(String id) {
   return id.matches("\\d{6}");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So in your case, I would have done `public boolean isValidID` instead.

Here, the compiler tells you to return something in case the length of the ID is not correct and the components of the ID (so the caracters) are between 0 and 9 (for example if your ID is something like `00ggg89`, then I suppose it is wrong, but if your ID is `000000`, then it could be right. Here is what I would have done

```
public boolean isValidID(String id) {
    return id.matches("[0-9]{6}");
}
```

Hope this helps ! :D

Comment: Why would you just `return id.matches("[0-9]{6}");`?

Comment: Also, you mean `-`, not `~`.

Answer (score -3):

```
public String isValidID(String id) {
    String result = "right";
        if(getId().length()!=6) {//checks for 6 digit id
            result =  "wrong";
        }
        else{//checks if digit contains invalid entry
            for(int i=0;i<getId().length();i++){
                if(Id.charAt(i)>'9'||Id.charAt(i)<'0')
                    result  = "wrong";
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Edit: In case the first statement is not valid it will never get to a return statement. Thats why you have to return a `String` in every possible case.

Comment: Please explain your answer. This is a question and answer site, not a provide the OP with code site, and the main benefit to the site is in the explanation. If your answer contains any code, it should be used to help demonstrate or amplify that which you've explained, not as the primary part of your answer.

Comment: Answers which simply dump code aren't good answers. Please explain what you are trying to show with your answer, why you need to do it like this etc.

Comment: You'll want to comment to anyone that commented to you after you've made your edit. To comment to @AndyTurner for instance, pre-pend an `@` in front of his name. This way we can change votes made (if he voted on your answer -- and you can't be 100% sure of that).